# Magnetic coexistence curves, and the magnetic Clapeyron equation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, magnetic-moment

Suppose I am interested in a simple magnetic system. In particular, in the phase diagram in the $B_e-T$ plane for a simple ferromagnet; assume no magnetocrystalline anisotropy and assume the external field $B_e$ to be always parallel to a fixed axis in space. These facts, I believe, let us consider the magnetic moment $I$ as the relevant extensive variable to be "added" in for consideration.

Now suppose there is somewhere that I can have two magnetic phases. I could be wrong, but I believe that under the assumptions above the only two phases can be a ferrmoagnetic ($f$) phase and a paramagnetic ($p$) phase. That is, we cannot have two different ferromagnetic domains. At any rate, this is not the crux of my question though a commentary from those more expert in EM theory would be appreciated.

If we consider the coexistence curve between whatever two phases are relevant, we obtain the Clapeyron equation in this magnetic case:
$$\left(\frac{dB_e}{dT}\right)_{cc} = - \frac{s_p - s_f}{i_p - i_f},$$
where $i_j$ is the magnetic moment per mole (in the given phase $j$. Now we have that $i_p - i_f < 0$ since the ferromagnetic phase will have a larger magnetic moment, and we also expect that $s_p > s_f$ since the paramagnetic phase is more disordered. Thus we expect $\left(\frac{dB_e}{dT} \right)_{cc} > 0$. But this seems to contradict what I remember from statistical mechanics, wherein this should be negative (see e.g. attached curve from Desmos, where $T$ would be on the $x$-axis). Such a curve clearly has a negative slope, so I am at a loss for what the discrepancy arises from.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ferromagnetic $ \Leftrightarrow $ paramagnetic phase transition is a second order one, the entropy is continuous across the phase boundary, and its latent entropy $s_p - s_f$ is zero.

---

This is Ehrenfest's construction for a 2nd order transition.
Starting from $d\mu=-SdT-IdB_e$ you get immediately that
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}=\frac{\partial I}{\partial T} \tag{1}$$
Then you also have
$$\left(\frac{dB_e}{dT}\right)_{cc} = - \frac{S_p - S_f}{I_p - I_f}\tag{2}$$ which you cannot use because the right side is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ but you can apply L'Hospital's rule and differentiate the numerator and denominator first wrt $T$ then $B_e$:

$$\left(\frac{dB_e}{dT}\right) =
-\frac{\frac{\partial S_p}{\partial T}-\frac{\partial S_f}{\partial T}}
{ \frac{\partial I_p}{\partial T}-\frac{\partial I_f}{\partial T}}=
-\frac{\Delta \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)}{\Delta \left(\frac{\partial I}{\partial T}\right)} \tag{3},$$
and
$$\left(\frac{dB_e}{dT}\right) =
-\frac{\frac{\partial S_p}{\partial B_e}-\frac{\partial S_f}{\partial B_e}}
{ \frac{\partial I_p}{\partial B_e}-\frac{\partial I_f}{\partial B_e}} =
-\frac{\Delta \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial B_e}\right)}{\Delta \left(\frac{\partial I}{\partial B_e}\right)}\tag{4}.$$
Now substitute (1) into (3) and (4) and you get
$$\Delta \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)=\left(\frac{dB_e}{dT}\right)^2\Delta \left(\frac{\partial I}{\partial B_e}\right)
\tag{5}$$ or
$$\Delta c_B=T\left(\frac{dB_e}{dT}\right)^2\Delta \left(\frac{\partial I}{\partial B_e}\right)
\tag{5a}$$ and
$$\Delta \left(\frac{\partial I}{\partial T}\right)=-\left(\frac{dB_e}{dT}\right)\Delta \left(\frac{\partial I}{\partial B_e}\right)
\tag{6}$$
In (5) and (6) $c_B$ is the heat capacity, and $\chi= \frac{\partial I}{\partial B_e}$ is the susceptibility.

Comment: Are you saying my derivation of the Clapeyron equation is wrong? And there should be a positive sign in front?

Comment: Your derivation of the Clapeyron equation is correct but what I wrote before was irrelevant.

Comment: I am confused then as to what phase transition is being discussed here — is it a phase transition between different ferromagnetic domains?

Comment: no, it is phase transition at the [Curie temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature) from ferro- to para-  or its reverse, I thought your question was about that.

Comment: That is curious then -- why is Callen asking us to consider the coexistence curve in this way if, as you say, it is a second-order transition? As far as I know, the Clapeyron equation is relevant for first-order transitions, no?

Comment: where is this in Callen?

Comment: Problem 9.3-8, though I have tried to adapt it to fit the description of a general question for this site.